# Does it take longer to rebuild a RAID5 array with more drives?

Tags: raid, nas

I have a NAS configured in RAID 5 with three 2tb drives that I'm replacing with four 4tb drives.

Given how long this operation is going to take, it's worth trying to figure out the optimal way to do it. Particularly because my primary reason for upgrading is to replace the old budget seagate drives with proper NAS drives and I'd rather minimize the chance of failure during this process.

my question: If I add one of the 4tb drives before replacing the others one-by-one, would that alleviate the strain on the two other drives during the rebuild? would it be quicker? or should I just rebuild the three old drives onto the new ones before adding the fourth? Is there anything else I should consider like migrating the array to a different form of raid?

Also: I understand the new drives will all be read as 2tb until I'm done with all the rebuilding and perform the additional step after I'm done with all the migrating.

Comment: No; You are going to have to rebuild the entire array. You will want to expand your storage with the 4th drive after you replace the original 3 drives.  However, it shouldn't take that long, to rebuild such a small amount of storage. However, different NAS solutions, are different.

Comment: Also, be aware that you are running RAID5 well outside spec/best practices - RAID5 is not considered robust with drives that large (its better then nothing - but make sure you have good backups).  Having all drives of the same age and manufacturer compounds your risk.

Comment: @Ramhound I read that I can expect each drive to take 10 hours to rebuild but I guess I'll find out. Starting the rebuild process.

Comment: I would be shocked if 2 TB of data took 10 hours to rebuild.  Hope you understand RAID 5 allows for 1 drive to fail.  Hopefully, you didn't buy those new drives all at once, common practice to purchase drives with vastly different manufacturing dates to avoid drives all failing at once.

Comment: Have you considered RAID10?  That will give you 8tb instead of 12tb, but 2 disks worth of redundancy and higher read speeds.  (if your nas has hardware RAID - most dont - RAID6 may give you better performance and more expandability and is worth considering as well )

Comment: @davidgo currently everything on the nas can be replicated by ripping disks or downloading things I own digitally. It's also my time machine but I guess I just hope my computer and NAS don't die at the same time. I am looking into cloud backup solutions but am also open to alternative raid configs if you have a suggestion.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't consider until just now that if a drive failed during the rebuild process I still have the old drives handy to rebuild the failed drive. Thanks!

Comment: What make/model or setup do you have for your NAS?

Comment: @davidgo I was looking into raid 10 but I am very confused about how 6 and 10 are practically different

Comment: @davidgo Western Digital mycloudex4100

Comment: RAID 10 uses data stripping and mirroring while RAID 5/6 only does stripping. RAID 6 provides additional protection due to the extra parity block.

Comment: @BooleanCheese If you have a larger number of drives the difference between raid 10 and raid 6 becomes very apparent. For example, with 8 2TB drives, raid 10 will give you 8TB usable space while raid 6 will allow 12TB.

Comment: @BooleanCheese is correct.  Another way to look at it is like this - RAID6 is like RAID5, but has 2 parity/check disks it can call on instead of 1.  RAID10 is like like RAID1  (ie mirroring) but has multiple disk pairs.

Comment: Per https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/wd/product/nas/my_cloud/my_cloud_ex4100/data-sheet-my-cloud-expert-series-ex4100.pdf it looks like your hardware does not support RAID6, but does support RAID10.   This makes sense because its 4 disks, so the amount of space available in RAID10 and RAID6 is the same, and as the device uses software RAID the processing overhead of RAID6 would be a problem - while RAID10 has a much lower overhead.

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for the info! I'm still rebuilding each of the 3 drives one-by-one but I think I'm gonna try to migrate it to raid10 if the software lets me. If it doesn't I'll probably do the migration at some point once I've got it backed up to some cloud service. I had plenty of free space as it was (with the 4tb usable capacity) so only having 8tb in raid 10 won't be a problem